# Get the count of form fields that were filled out?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Facility,DateCreated,CreateUsername,DateLastModified,LastModifiedUsername,SupervisorComplete,DeptManagerComplete,SafetyManagerComplete,SupervisorDateCompleted,DeptManagerDateCompleted,SafetyManagerDateCompleted,Deleted,CorrectiveActionComplete,CorrectiveActionDateCompleted,HospitalName,EmailSent")] AccidentSupervisor accidentSupervisor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Add AccidentSupervisor
            DB.AccidentSupervisors.Add(accidentSupervisor);
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(accidentSupervisor);
    }
```

I basically want to have a count from the accidentSupervisor object that is the number of fields filled out on the form from the previous page.  For example, if a textbox is left empty or a checkbox is left unchecked, it is not included in the count.  Is this something that is possible to set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int count = accidentSupervisor.GetType()
                 .GetProperties()
                 .Select(s => s.GetValue(accidentSupervisor, null))
                 .Count(c => c != null);
```